# Add user data to the logging context from the request

Tags: logging, nestjs

It is necessary to add to the logging context at the level of the entire application the user data from the request received after JWT validation in the Nest.js application.

To create logs I use nestjs-pino. This package has the ability to customize the context through the `customProps` property. The req.user property is populated after authorization is completed via the JWT.

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { LoggerModule } from "nestjs-pino";
import { MyModule } from "./my/my.module";

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      exclude: [],
      pinoHttp: {
        // here
        customProps: (req) => ({
          user: {
            userId: req.user?.id,
            scopes: req.user?.scopes,
          },
        }),
        transport: {
          target: "pino-pretty",
          options: {
            singleLine: true,
          },
        },
      },
    }),
    MyModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Sample output:

```
[18:07:50.030] INFO (10536): request completed {"req":{"id":1,"method":"GET","url":"/api/v1/my","query":{},"params":{"0":"v1/my"}},"user":{"userId":"12345678","scopes":["ManageData","ReadData"]},"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":29}
```

But when using the logger in the module service, the user property is not filled, because the context in pino is filled only after the request is completed.

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common'


@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(MyService.name)

  getTestData() {
    const data = 'test-data'

    this.logger.log('Getting test data')

    return data
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
[18:07:50.010] INFO (10536): Getting test data {"req":{"id":1,"method":"GET","url":"/api/v1/my","query":{},"params":{"0":"v1/my"}},"user":{/** empty */},"context":"MyService"}
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { Logger, LoggerErrorInterceptor } from 'nestjs-pino'

/** ... */

app.useLogger(app.get(Logger))
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggerErrorInterceptor())

/** ... */
```

I would be very grateful if you could tell me a universal solution without passing user data from the controller to each method of the service.

Comment: what if you use `Logger` from `nestjs-pino` and `@InjectPinoLogger()` at `MyService` instead?

Comment: If you are talking about it: 

@InjectPinoLogger(MyService.name)
private readonly logger: PinoLogger.

Properties with a user are also not embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a customer serializer to make that work the way you want. Try updating your `pinoHttp` configuration to include a `serializers` block like the one shown below.

I've had success in getting this to work for including user information in all Pino log messages.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      exclude: [],
      pinoHttp: {
        // here
        customProps: (req) => ({
          user: {
            userId: req.user?.id,
            scopes: req.user?.scopes,
          },
        }),
        transport: {
          target: "pino-pretty",
          options: {
            singleLine: true,
          },
        },
        // This section allows you to control the output for each
        // request (you can also add serializers for the response,
        // etc.). Using 'req.raw' in your serializer code should
        // give you access to the raw request data, including your
        // user information.
        serializers: {
          req: (req) => {
            return {
              id: req.raw.id,
              method: req.raw.method,
              ... [other req key/values here as desired] ...
              user: {
                userId: req.raw.user?.id,
                scopes: req.raw.user?.scopes,
              },
            };
          },
        },
      },
    }),
    MyModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
```